# Using scp with large files kills ethernet?

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, ethernet, hardware-recommendation

This morning I tried to use [scp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_copy) to copy a single large file from my old Linux Ubuntu machine to my brand new 2017 Mac Book Pro. I ran into a very strange problem: scp would happily copy 95% of data (around 150 MB/sec) - to then "stall", and at some point tell me about broken connection. Afterwards, I basically had no more LAN access.

This happened on MacOs Sierra. What could be the reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out: the culprit was neither the Mac itself, nor my Linux box.

I later found that the [LogiLink](http://www.logilink.com/Products_LogiLink/Active_Network_Components/Gigabit/USB-C_to_Gigabit_Adapter.htm) USB-C to Ethernet adapter caused this.

And for the record - there were various other symptoms, such as:

- download of large files in my browser being extra slow
- replicating large files via IBM Notes not only being slow, but basically turning the whole machine into "almost unresponsive" mode